# fillViewPort behavior in Jetpack Compose Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there something like `ScrollView` `fillViewPort` in Jetpack Compose `Column`?

See this example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FillViewPortIssue() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        for (i in 0..5) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(72.dp)
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        ) {
            Text("Ok")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

When the device is in landscape, the content is cropped, because there's no scroll.
If I add the `verticalScroll` modifier do the `Column`...

```kotlin
    ...
    Column(
        Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) // <<-- this
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
    ...
```

... the scroll problem is fixed, but the button goes up, like this.

[image]

In the traditional toolkit, we can fix this using `ScrollView` + `fillViewPort` property. Is there something equivalent to Compose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change the order of the modifiers worked...
Thanks to Abhishek Dewan (from Kotlin Slack channel)!

```
Column(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize() // first, set the max size
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) // then set the scroll
) {
```

Comment: As of compose 1.0.2 this doesn't work, even when order is changed.

Comment: I ran the same sample on compose 1.0.2 and still working for me.

Comment: I need the use of fill Viewport in Landscape mode, where all my content should be scrolled (In Portrait I have used weight to fill the view). But your solution is not working in that case.

Comment: also if you need to fill all the space for last element up to the bottom then you also should use weight 1f instead of fillMaxSize

Comment: It actually works, though you might have to rearrange your composables, because fillMaxSize won't work if you add this modifier to children of this composable because of the way vertical scroll modifier works

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue recently and substituted `verticalScroll` for `scrollable(rememberScrollState(), Orientation.Vertical)` which seemed to work for my case and allow the screen to fill its viewport while allowing scrolling

Comment: Somehow this works for me, while the accepted answer doesn't. However, the scroll requires manual handling in this case :(